# Stop Google from javascript execution

Tags: javascript, seo, bots

I have a link protection on my site to prevent search robots from scanning it, this protection based on javascript href replacing on page onload (which initially encoded and prefixed by '#' like this:

```
<a href="#real_link_crunched_here">...</a>
```

I know that Google can execute javascript now and therefore can follow to "protected" links. 
Is it right way to prevent javascript execution by Google bot (and other bots too) ?

Comment: What's wrong with [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)?

Answer (score 3):

@Epsiloncool there is no absolute way to prevent a bot from doing something a user can do in the browser... the only way to do such a thing would be via captcha.  You *COULD* bind to the mouseover event to swap out the link then, which *may* work better.

I would suggest adding the `rel="nofollow"` attribute to the A element(s), at least then bots that respect such action can do what they need.

You *could* also have a form on the page, and bind such actions to change the post url, and then submit that form to the next page.  a BOT should *NEVER* do an HTTP POST.  However, any bot that would, is already ignoring the rel=nofollow.

Comment: Bots can get around captchas, by the way.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I am aware of that... just the same, it's the only thing approaching a user driven solution... also, bots can't do all types of captchas easily.  They aren't all obfuscated numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `robots.txt` file to tell legitimate robots what URLs not to load, or you cah do `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` in the `<head>` block of the pages you don't want indexed.

You can also do `<a rel="nofollow">` to get Google to ignore those link tags.

Comment: Robots.txt method is not fit, I don't want to disable whole page, but only prevent link following. Metatags and rel is also bad idea, because not all scanning bots follow these rules. I need to absolutely hide that links from scanning.

Comment: You will never be able to block all bots. Malicious bots often pose as real users as closely as possible specifically so you *can't* block them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you alreadys have a `robots.txt`in place, if you are looking for more advanced methods of "defense". If they are friendly bots, they will make themselves discovarable in the `user-agent` string, but if not, they will probably call themselves `internet explorer` and ignore your `robots.txt`. You still can put a turing test in place, i guess...

You could still put some incredibly simply puzzle on your start page, to get rid of them, i guess, but that might alienate some visitors as well.

Here's a list of different bot user agents, if you want to look into that:
http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/